# Crear hilos dentro de un ciclo

Tags: c#, hilos

tengo un problema no logro entender como crear hilos dentro de un ciclo y que se vayan ejecutando simultaneamente todos, y cuando finalicen todos los hilos enviar un mensaje .

Tengo este codigo:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileList[i]))//valida que exista el archivo
    {
        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileList[i]);
        if (finfo.Extension == ".ctl") //valida que solo sean CTL
        {
            ExecuteBatFile(path, finfo.Name);//ejecuta proceso
        }
    }
}
```

y es el procedimiento que ejecuta el archivo  .batch

```
// proceso para ejecutar un archivo .batch
 public  void ExecuteBatFile(string _path, string _archivoCTL)
        {

            CrearBatch(_path, _archivoCTL);
            Process proc = null;
            try
            {
                string targetDir = string.Format(_path);   //this is where mybatch.bat lies
                proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDir;
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = _archivoCTL.Substring(0, _archivoCTL.Length - 4) + ".bat";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");  //this is argument
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;  //this is for hiding the cmd window...so execution will happen in back ground.
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occurred :{0},{1}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

mi duda es en donde crear los hilos para que se vayan ejecutando simultaneamente( para que se ejecute el ExecuteBatFile) e ir revisando si ya terminaron todos.

Muchas gracias por su asesoria. !!!

Answer (score 1):

Crear un hilo por cada tarea que se hace generalmente es una mala idea, si creas 50 hilos no significa que todos los hilos se ejecuten al mismo tiempo pues lo procesadores solo pueden ejecutar una cantidad limitada tareas simultáneamente, y si tu objetivo es ejecutar las tareas mas rápido al crear muchos hijos vas a obtener el resultado contrario. Lo mas optimo es crear un hilo por cada core del procesador (asumiendo que no hay mas aplicaciones corriendo en el mismo PC) y crear una cola donde se colocan las tareas a ejecutar donde los hilos van removiendo de la cola las tareas que ejecutan. C# ofrece una clase que optimiza la creación de hilos. Ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileList[i]))//valida que exista el archivo
    {
       FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileList[i]);
       if (finfo.Extension == ".ctl") //valida que solo sean CTL
       {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( ExecuteBatFile());//colocar la tarea en la cola para ser ejecutada por alguno de los hilos del thread pool
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, en base a tu comentario, lo he realizado de la siguiente manera:

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, en base a tu comentario lo he dejado de la siguiente forma:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(fileList[i]))//valida que exista el archivo
                        {
                            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileList[i]);
                              if (finfo.Extension == ".ctl") //valida que solo sean CTL
                                {
                               ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                                    new WaitCallback(delegate (object state)
                                            { ExecuteBatFile(path, finfo.Name); }), null);
                                //clLog.Log("Ejecuta archivo batch " + finfo.Name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Gracias !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si usas .net 4.5 (o superior) y Visual Studio 2012 por lo menos,  lo recomendable es hacer que el método sea asíncrono con la palabra async:

```
private async Task MetodoAsincrono(string path, string archivoCTL)
{
    await Task.Run(() => ExecuteBatFile(path, archivoCTL));
}
```

Luego, para usarlo:

```
 private async Task EjecutaAsincrono()
 {
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileList[i]))//valida que exista el archivo
        {
            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(fileList[i]);
            if (finfo.Extension == ".ctl") //valida que solo sean CTL
            {
                tasks.Add(MetodoAsincrono(path, finfo.Name)); // agregamos una a una cada tarea
            }
        }
   }

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()); // ejecutamos todas las tareas programadas y espera a que terminen
  // aquí envías el mensaje
}
```

En la actualidad, lo recomendable es usar async/await para tareas asíncronas. No le veo lógica a usar ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem cuando existen async/await, ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem es una api super anticuada (.net 1.1), ya no se recomienda, a menos que estés anclado en versiones antiguas del framwork.

Comment: Excelente observacion Luis, modificare mi codigo para que no sea tan anticuado , muchas gracias !!!